# What's an easy CMS for restricting users from certain pages?

Tags: web, content-management-system

Hi,
What's an easy CMS for restricting users from certain pages? CMS features are important, but my interest is a built-in solution for restricting users from certain pages (based on customer ID). Here's my objective.

One, restrict pages from certain users. Two, have multiple ID's and privileges for users. An easy solution for managing page and user access is my reason for looking for a new CMS system. I've looked at Wordpress, WildApricot, Magento, and SurrealCMS. What would you recommend?

I need simple front-end solution I can use with an ftp server. "If I have to know the type of server, that's not easy." I just want to make it clear what I'm considering. I look forward to your reply.
Thanks,
DisEngaged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) will do this no problem, as will anything built on django since it has [authentication and permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization) built-in as a first-class part of the framework.

I also hear good things about [Django CMS](https://www.django-cms.org/en/), although I haven't used it.

Comment: I ended up using Wild Apricot. Thanks for the suggestions.